# Any way to profile code for cache behavior?

Tags: c++, windows, caching, profiling

As the title says I'd like to somehow get the cache behavior of my code. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit edition, compiling on Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition, compiling C++ code.

I understand that there's Valgrind under Linux, but are there any free alternatives I could use, or methods otherwise?

Comment: Is that actually possible? I was under the impression it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/) will give you pretty detailed cache and pipeline analysis. It's not cheap though. I believe some level/edition of VS (I remember it was "team edition" on XP) had a decent profiler.

Comment: Thanks, I gave the evaluation copy a shot. I wasn't aware they had such a thing. It worked well for my needs and this may be what I'll end up purchasing in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AQTime`. I'm pretty sure that some of it options include cache profiling.